# Changing owner of an external hard drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

My understanding of code is about zero. I can open a terminal window, and type commands that are given to me, but that's about it.

I have an external hard drive with two partitions. I bought this drive when my operating system was Apple, 10.5 or so, and it was formatted as HFS+ with that system. Now, connecting the HDD to my Linux system, I can read files, but I have about 1.5 TB of space that I can't use, because I am not the owner of these files, so can't write to the HDD.

Short of reformatting the HDD, is there a way for me to set the permissions for the HDD so I can write to it?

Comment: You need to *remove* that file or just *write* into it?

Answer (score 3):

Your root account will be able to set ownership of any file. Open a terminal and switch to root, with the command `sudo -i`.

Next, identify the path at which the partition is mounted (run `mount` command) and hopefully you can tell which partition is which in the output.

Then you can `chown -R youruser:yourgroup /path/to/mounted/partition` to change the ownership to your user and group.

Answer (score 0):

Go to files, other locations, mount the required hdd and then open it ,now on the left upper corner you will see its name right click on it and select properties and click on permissions and then select the required option ,example:- to read and write and save, hope this works .I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: Did this worked?@Thomas Ballew